# Can't use python requests to download flie in a webpage. (can be accessed by Chrome)

Tags: python, ajax, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to download an XHR file from [website](https://markets.businessinsider.com/bond/historical/canadacd-bonds_201921-bond-2021-ca135087j884) that contains the historical price. This file can be accessed by Chrome(as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfmAl.png)).  Here is the url of the file [file link](https://markets.businessinsider.com/Ajax/BondController_HistoricPriceList/canadacd-bonds_201921-bond-2021-ca135087j884/STU/20.12.2019_20.1.2020) (If you click this link the webpage will show the file is not found because your browser sent a GET request and the file request method is POST.) But the point is the returned status code in Chrome is 200 but when I use python to simulate a post request, the returned status code is 500 (i.e. can't access).

Here is the code:

```
import requests
header = { "origin": "https://markets.businessinsider.com",
           "referer": "https://markets.businessinsider.com/bond/historical/5_750-canada-government-of-bond-2029-ca135087wl43",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36",
           "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
           "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
           "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = 'https://markets.businessinsider.com/Ajax/BondController_HistoricPriceList/canadacd-bonds_201921-bond-2021-ca135087j884/STU/20.12.2019_20.1.2020'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(header)
print(s.post(url).status_code)
```

Output:

```
500
```

Comment: please [edit] your post to add in error messages. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: please provide some output in the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write your question and add more information.
In Python you can do something like this

```py
import urllib.request
url = 'https://markets.businessinsider.com/bond/historical/canadacd-bonds_201921-bond-2021-ca135087j884'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   html = response.read()
print(html)
```

And using requests you can do

```py
import requests as req
resp = req.get(url)
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: I just tried your method and I got an error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found". As mentioned above, the file request method is POST and here is GET. But thank you.

Comment: If you just put a post in ```resp = req.post(url)``` , it will work. Give us more information on what exactly are you trying to do, why a POST ? for example. Your question has been downgraded because of lack of clarity I think. But we want to help you

Comment: I uploaded a picture in the description that describes the file that was downloaded by Chrome and I want to download this file by using python. Because the request method in the picture is post, I want to use python to simulate a post request to get the data in the file. (correct me if I am wrong)